# perspective-origin css not working in firefox 30.0.1

Tags: css, firefox, animation, perspective

I have an html div's right here
`<div id="div1">
<a href="<?=BASEURL;?>home/aboutus">
  <div id="div2" align="center">T<br /> E<br /> S<br /> T<br /> I<br /> N<br /> G</div>
</a>
</div>` 
And the css code right here

```
#div1 {
position: relative;
margin: auto;
height: 250;
width: 200px;
padding: 10px;
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-webkit-perspective: 125px;
-webkit-animation: mymove 2.5s infinite;
/* Standard syntax */
perspective: 125px;
animation: mymove 2.5s infinite;
right:0;
margin-right:-210px;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
50% {-webkit-perspective-origin: 10px 50%;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes mymove {
50% {perspective-origin: 10px 50%;}
}

#div2 {
padding: 10px;
position: absolute;
background:linear-gradient(#333,#000,#000);
color:#effcd4;
-webkit-transform: rotateX(344deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
transform: rotateY(344deg);
border: 1px solid #d2ff30;
border-radius:1em;
}
#div2:hover{
-webkit-transform: rotateX(5deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
transform: rotateX(5deg);
color:#d2ff30;
}
```

Now all of these seems to work in google chrome but not in firefox version 30.0.1. Can somebody please help me? and if time permits, can you explain why it doesn't work? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found the problem and fixed it, just gonna post it so that it may help someone who would face the same problem in the future.

I had:

```
<div id="div1">
<a href="mysite.com/home/aboutus">
<div id="div2" align="center">T<br /> E<br /> S<br /> T<br /> I<br /> N<br /> G</div>
</a>
</div>
```

And the culprit was the `<a href=""></a>` tags

It should be like the code bellow. So we learned that div's with animations should not be placed inside a link tag. Cheers!

```
<div id="div1">
<div id="div2" align="center">T<br /> E<br /> S<br /> T<br /> I<br /> N<br /> G</div>
</div>
```